# Memory management - finding bugs earlier

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I just spent a lot of time debugging a dumb mistake, (releasing a variable that I hadn't allocated) and wondered if there's a way to have XCode's Analyze warn me next time.  The code was something like this:

```
@synthesize alfa, beta;
…
NSString *temp1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"AlfaText];
self.alfa = temp1;
[temp1 release];

NSString *temp2 = @"BetaText";
self.beta = temp2;
[temp2 release]
```

The last statement is (obviously?) a bug.  Analyze seems to do a good job of reporting when you have too few [release]s, and having too many seems to be just as analyzable.  Is there something that can be turned on that I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, the last statement is a bug, but it won't break anything.  String constants have a retain count of `INT_MAX`, and their `-retain`, `-release`, and `-autorelease` messages are overridden to be no-ops.

Comment: But if temp2 was NSArray, rather than NSString, then it could break, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the static analyzer didn't catch that, please file a bug.   It really should have.

If you convert your projects to use ARC, both the lack of writing retain/release at all combined with the better analysis performed by the compiler will lead to many fewer memory management bugs.